# How to update java console JRE?

Tags: java, jnlp

I am trying to run a java application(jnlp) but problem is when I start this application it tries to use JRE version 1.8.0_121-b13. How can I change this java version to java 1.6?

```
Java Web Start 11.121.2.13 x86
Using JRE version 1.8.0_121-b13 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
m:   print memory usage
....
```

Both User and System JRE versions are 1.6

[image]

When I download this jar file and try to run with command

```
java -jar sample.jar
```

from console, System using java 1.6 to run this application.

**EDIT:**

Output of

```
java -version

java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
```

My jnlp file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="***mysite***"  href="sample.jnlp">

<information>
    <title>Sample jnlp</title>        
    <offline-allowed/>
</information>


<security>
    <all-permissions />
</security>

<resources>
    <j2se version="1.5+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
    <jar href="sample.jar" main="true" />
    <property name="jnlp.packEnabled" value="true" />
</resources>

<application-desc name="sample" main-class="com.test.main">
</application-desc>

<update check="always" policy="always"/>

</jnlp>
```

Comment: I dont get your last sentence. Are you saying: when you invoke java manually on the command line, you know how to pick java 1.6?

Comment: @GhostCat No I mean When I run this jar file from command line system using java 1.6 to run this application as expected. But why It tries to use java 1.8 when I try to run this application from web? See my edit also

Comment: What is Java version your application server is using, please check that out first

Comment: @murthy It is also using java 1.6

Comment: If possible, can you paste the Log of that snippet, as there seems to be something fishy

Comment: @murthy There is no error or something like that. Only problem is it tries to use java 1.8 instead of java 1.6 and it causes some problems.

Comment: @hellzone, This means clearly that the server is installed or it is using 1.8. You need to check the classpath and related settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem will most likely be that the JNLP file for the application (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#example) *specifies* that the application *requires* Java 8 or later.   And the chances are that if you somehow managed to get the application launcher to use Java 6, the app would fail because it depends on Java 8 libraries.

You need to install a Java 8 JRE:

- to get the app to run<sup>1</sup>, and
- because Java 6 is beyond end-of-life and no longer getting security patches.

(Just like WindowsXP isn't: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WannaCry_ransomware_attack_)

---

**UPDATE** - Try forcing JNLP to use a specific version of Java; e.g. replace

```
<j2se version="1.5+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
```

with

```
<j2se version="1.6" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
```

I suspect that it might be `javaws` itself that is trying to stop you from accidentally using a deprecated / insecure Java release.

---

<sup>1 - OK, your comments suggest that the app will run using Java 6 if you run it from the command line.  In that case, the likely reason that the JNLP configs on that website specify Java 8 is because *they* are sending you a strong message that you should update.  Using JNLP launching and Java 6 is a security risk, unless you are paying for a Java 6 support contract from Oracle, and you are patching your JRE regularly.</sup>

Comment: I added my jnlp file. Problem is I have created this jnlp file manually and I didn't specify to use java 1.8.

Comment: Still not worked. I have removed java 1.8(jre 1.8 32 bit) then when I tried to start jnlp(and any jar file) again it shows "How do you want to open this file" dialog. Problem is I also got java 1.8(jre 1.8 64 bit) and java 1.6(jdk 1.6 64 bit).

Comment: I thought your question specified that you *want* to use Java 6.  If you (now) want to use Java 8, then I suggest: 1) uninstall all JDKs and JREs (don't just delete the directories ...),  2) install Java 8 (JDK or JRE) **only**, 3) change the JNLP file to version=`1.8+`.

Comment: The problem with Java on Windows is that there is some opaque stuff to do with Java and the registry.  (One of many reason why I steer clear of Windows ...)

Comment: My normal trick of looking at the OpenJDK source code for clues is NOT WORKING ... 'cos it seems that the webstart code is not in the OpenJDK repo's.  Grrrrr.

Comment: Removed all versions of jdk and jre and only installed jre 1.6 .After that I just manually set windows to open jnlp files with javaws(under jre 1.6) and jar files with javaw(under jre 1.6). This is the only way I think. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: *"I suspect that it might be `javaws` itself that is trying to stop you from accidentally using a deprecated / insecure Java release."* It seems Oracle removed the option to use an older JRE some time ago. I have seen no official announcement about it though.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - It is probably hidden in release notes.